# Docker compose $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile that runs perfectly on it's own.

But when I run it from `docker-compose up --build`

I get: `$GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not`

Below is a snippet of terminal output.

```
Successfully tagged app_app:latest
Starting golang_db ... done
Starting golang_app ... done
Attaching to golang_db, golang_app
golang_app | $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not
.
.
golang_db | Version: '5.6.48'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
golang_app exited with code 1
```

Any suggestions?

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: ./MySQL
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
    container_name: golang_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    tty: true
  app:
    build:
      context: ./Go
    volumes:
      - "./Go:/go"
    container_name: golang_app
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - db
```

```
#Go/Dockerfile
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./structs.go .
COPY ./handlers.go .
COPY ./server.go .
COPY ./favicon.ico .
COPY ./assets /assets
RUN go mod init stuff.com
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build $(ls -1 *.go)
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["go", "run", "."]
```

```
#MySQL/Dockerfile
FROM mysql:5.6
COPY test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql
```

Comment: Why are you building the app (incorrectly BTW, use package names with `go build`), then building it again every time you start the container with `go run`?

Comment: Also, what is GOPATH in the container? What are you building that image from? It's also strange that you add the files, then copy them some again individually. What else is being added?

Comment: Dockerfile updated.
I get the same behavior when I do docker-compose up

Comment: And why `go build` executable is not used instead of doing a `go run` every time a container is run?

Answer (score 2):

In the root of your GOPATH no packages are expected. The expectation is usually to have a subdirectory src/github.com/someproject/somerepo, which is most likely the root cause of the warning

Answer (score -4):

I sorted it out, the Dockerfile above has been updated.

Comment: You should post an answer and not edit your question. Now there's no easy way to know how you solved it.

Comment: You should not post an answer if its not an answer, period. This is not an answer, its just a personal progress update.